# Microsoft/fast-element attribute change

Tags: web-component

Following the getting started with FAST element guide [here](https://www.fast.design/docs/fast-element/getting-started), I don't understand why the value of the attribute is not changing whenever I use the element in.

Even when following the guide completely by basically copying and pasting the sample code, I can't make it work.

Based on the code and markup below, I would expect that the `h3` element has the value of `test` and not `default`.

Anybody who has same issue, or know what I might be doing wrong?

Btw, I'm using `esbuild` to bundle, transpile and serve the files.

```js
import { FASTElement, customElement, attr, html } from "@microsoft/fast-element";

const template = html`
        <div class="header">
        <h3>My name is: ${x => x.greeting}</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="name-tag-body">
        <slot>Default slot</slot>
    </div>
`;

@customElement({
    name: 'name-tag',
    template: template
})
export class NameTag extends FASTElement {
    @attr greeting: string = "default";

    greetingChanged() {
        console.log("greeting changed:", this.greeting);   
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        super.connectedCallback();
        console.log("connectedCallback");
      }
}  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <name-tag greeting="something"></name-tag>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to have the `target` property of the `tsconfig.json` file set to something other than `ESNext`. `ES2016` works fine.